# How do nginx dynamic modules work?

Tags: nginx

I wonder how dynamic modules actually work with a custom installation of Nginx.

- Are they already compiled ?
- In that case, does that mean worker processes use them in sub processes ?
- If not, how do they get added to the core binaries ?
- Why don't we just include them in the core binaries to increase performance ?

Please help me I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0):

> Are they already compiled ?

It depends on if the package creator has compiled and included the dynamic modules.

> In that case, does that mean worker processes use them in sub processes ?

I don't understand exactly what you mean by this. The code in dynamic modules is just just like other code in nginx. Only the loading mechanism is different.

> If not, how do they get added to the core binaries ?

They are loaded during startup to memory and hooked into the request processing flow. They are not added to core binaries.

> Why don't we just include them in the core binaries to increase performance ?

I don't think there is any difference in performance between dynamic and static modules.

It is pointless to include all modules in core binaries, since there would be dead code for most people. Dead code still uses memory when loaded.

Also, release process would be really painful. In addition to the core modules, you would need to decide what changes from all the other modules to include in a release. That would increase the time release takes.

Comment: What do you mean they're loaded during startup ? Don't you have to recompile a binary in order to makes changes to it ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you need to recompile a binary to make changes to it. However, in this case, nginx binary is built so that you can add extra functionality with dynamic modules.